# integrate an R script in PHP

Tags: php, r

I'm trying to integrate an R script in PHP to show a graphic.
For this I used the example given  in this site http://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-php-and-r/ and it works.

After some adjustments, I tested my code in the browser, but nothing happened. But if i test it in the IDE Geany code it works fine.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? And how can I solve this problem?

This is my R code:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
n=as.integer(args[1]);
library(gdata);
casa=setwd("/var/www")
fpath = file.path(casa, "Azevedo_JAM_final.xls");
dados = read.xls(fpath, header=F);
#(irrelevant code to the problem)

png(filename="medias.png", width=800, height=800)
barplot(df$vmedia, main="Medias", names.arg=df$vlabels,cex.names=0.6,las=2)
dev.off();
```

This my php code

```
<?php

  $N = 2;

  exec("Rscript infografics.r $N"); 

  // return image tag
  echo("<img src='medias.png?' />");

?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Does the webserver have the rights to execute that r-file?

Comment: Just install [RApache](http://rapache.net) to perk up :)

Comment: @daroczig I just installed, now what? Just call the php file in the browser?

Comment: @MisssCat: for such simple things, forget PHP and use `brew` in one file. Read the docs of RApache (linked above) and [this neat tutorial about usage](http://rlamp.blogspot.hu/). The [useR2007](http://data.vanderbilt.edu/~hornerj/brew/useR2007.rhtml) demo of Jeff is great to check out too (sources can be found in the [docs](http://rapache.net/manual.html#rapache_Cookbook)).

Answer (score -1):

This works fine for me. Cheers!

http://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-php-and-r/